# I don't know if it is a good practice to put values from database in html id attribute

Tags: php, html

I am at my first php project and I'm learning a lot.

In my project, i used to put in html id attribute values from my database, to make my work easier.
For example:

```
<a id="nameOfMyTable_ID"> some link... </a>
<a id="idOfRow_idOfForeignKey_idOfCurrentUser"> .... </a>
```

It's that ok, or i'm doing it wrong ?.... I don't know for sure if that is a good practice.
It's there any chance for vulnerability ?

I'm sorry, the qustion may sound stupid for some of you, but I really don't know if i'm doing wright.

Comment: The question is *why*? What were you gaining by building such complex IDs?

If your purpose is building unique IDs across pages, that's fine, if somewhat verbose. But if you're *extracting* that data for use in your app, you should be using `data` attributes.

Comment: There is a chance for cross-site scripting (XSS) vulns if the values are generated by users (as opposed to only auto-increment ids from the db).  Whenever you place dynamic values in HTML attributes, use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with the `ENT_QUOTES` option.   `id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val_from_database, ENT_QUOTES); ?>"`

Comment: I need those id's afterward...i post some id's to my controller, where i make different operations on my database..

Comment: Dan - see my answer. You are using the ID's to pass to a controller, so you need to put them in the href attribute instead of the id attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to put it as a comment but got a bit big:

The chances at vulnerabilities will depend on how you process those values before/after presenting them to the user (and I'm sure that you are applying fixes for them):

- As Michael said in a comment, there's a possibility for XSS if you don't sanitize the values before you write them on your HTML;
- Also, take into account that these IDs are in the client's side, you will need to sanitize them properly before using them in the database to avoid possible SQL injection;
- Finally, even if you sanitize them and they are correct, you'll need to double check that the values are valid and compatible. For example, imagine your ID being `idOfRow_idOfForeignKey_idOfCurrentUser` with a value of 1_23_45, but I change it somehow to 1_34_78. What would happen then? Is the code ready for that or will I be updating somebody else's record?

I don't know if the way IDs are displayed on the post can be considered as a good practice, personally I wouldn't do it that way, and even if I did, I'd follow some rules:

- Never trust user input. And what better way to explain it than with humor: http://xkcd.com/327/... Sanitize all input, use parameterized queries.
- Never trust your own input. Even if you think you are the source, the values that you are reading from the database may have been provided by a user through a web form. Sanitize all output.
- Verify that the data provided is valid. Even if you sanitize the data, it comes from an "unknown" user, they may have changed the IDs manually. E.g.: double check that the user ID that is performing the operation has permissions to do so.
- Put the values in the right place. Why put the current user ID in the tag ID? It should be somewhere else: a session variable, or if you want to have it available on the client side, a hidden input/variable; and for the other IDs, they probably should go in the `href` or in a `data-` attribute.
- Provide the least possible information to the user. Users do not need to know your IDs, they don't need to know data tables/column names... A "good person" will not need them, a "bad person" may use them against you.

I tried to focus on the ones that would apply to the example in the question (although they'd apply to any project), and probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the user's id into the id attribute of an `<a>` tage, I'll assume you are trying to link to a page that needs the user's id. In this case, you would instead want to pass the user's id as a `GET` parameter in the link.

Replace

```
<a id="idOfRow_idOfForeignKey_idOfCurrentUser">...</a>
```

With

```
<a href="myOtherPage.php?id=<?=$userID?>"> .... </a>
```

Note: I changed your variable from `$idOfRow_idOfForeignKey_idOfCurrentUser` to `$userID` to make it a little cleaner, but the idea is to simply pass the User's id to the next page using the `href` attribute